# Is there a better way to convert a Scala Map to Java Map?

Tags: java, scala, dictionary, type-conversion

I found a solution, but it is not too elegant:

```
mapAsJavaMap(Map("param1"->someObject, "param2"->otherObject ))
```

I found some examples containing "asJava" calls, but it is not working in my configuration of Scala 2.10.X.

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is object [JavaConverters](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.JavaConverters%24) that will do the trick for you:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters.mapAsJavaMapConverter

Map("param1"-> 1, "param2"-> 2).asJava
//> res0: java.util.Map[String,Int] = {param1=1, param2=2}
```

Edit: It is indeed a bad programming habbit to use wildcard imports as they will clutter your namespace and they might introduce accidental implicit conversion/values into the scope. So changed wildcard import to explicit import.

Comment: How is this different from OP code (hint -- don't use `._` in import)? Downvoted.

Comment: @om-nom-nom: There are places where importing everything in a package or object is perfectly reasonable, and I personally think this is one of them.

Comment: <s>@Lauri how is this different from snippet that nyuwec (Original Poster) provided in hist question? </s> In fact I was more against other issue (not related directly to the imports), which is, in fact, just my misunderstanding of your answer. Sorry for messing you up, reverted downvote.

Comment: Since the conversions only happen if you explicitly invoke `asJava`, a symbol I would be extraordinarily unlikely to use otherwise, I don't have any qualms about using a wildcard import with these converters.  IIRC there is another conversion package which does not require you to invoke anything, and yes, I'd be careful with that one.